# Adding jars to classpath, Eclipse, Android

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, classpath

Currently, I go to properties-> build path-> libraries -> and then add external jars to my classpath, I know this is the correct way to do this, for java at least. However, the issue is I am running it on the Android SDK 2.1. When I run the program, I do not think the android emulator can "find" the .jars in the classpath. Is this possible? If so, which folder do I put the jars before adding them to my classpath?

Comment: no. this is the correct way. something else is wrong.

Comment: Refer to this [link](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Eclipse/article.html#classpath_jar) For Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 3):

You can try doing it in eclipse by

```
Right Click the jar --> Build Path --> Add to build path
```

Comment: I assume you mean the jar I am adding to my classpath? Ill try and do that when I get back to my house

Answer (score 1):

1) Go to your Finder / Explorer and select your .jar files
2) Drag your .jar files into Eclipse, (make sure to put them in your desired Project)
3) right click on each jar -> "build path" -> "add to build path"

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of the LogCat?

if you are using native code in your projects you must include the so files in libs->armeabi folder. stuff like box2d, chipmunk, xml2, etc...