# mr nom cannot execute

Tags: java, mobile

I've got a problem with mrnom (from the Mario Zechner's book https://code.google.com/p/beginning-android-games/ ), when I execute it on eclipse the emulator said "Unfortunately, Mr Nom has stopped" and the log cat say...

**logcat**

```
    11-07 15:21:55.573: W/dalvikvm(641): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/badlogic/androidgames/mrnom/MrNom; (445)
11-07 15:21:55.573: W/dalvikvm(641): Link of class 'Lcom/badlogic/androidgames/mrnom/MrNom;' failed
11-07 15:21:55.573: D/AndroidRuntime(641): Shutting down VM
11-07 15:21:55.573: W/dalvikvm(641): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
11-07 15:21:55.583: E/AndroidRuntime(641): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-07 15:21:55.583: E/AndroidRuntime(641): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.badlogic.androidgames.mrnom/com.badlogic.androidgames.mrnom.MrNom}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.badlogic.androidgames.mrnom.MrNom
11-07 15:21:55.583: E/AndroidRuntime(641):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
11-07 15:21:55.583: E/AndroidRuntime(641):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
11-07 15:21:55.583: E/AndroidRuntime(641):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-07 15:21:55.583: E/AndroidRuntime(641):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
11-07 15:21:55.583: E/AndroidRuntime(641):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-07 15:21:55.583: E/AndroidRuntime(641):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-07 15:21:55.583: E/AndroidRuntime(641):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-07 15:21:55.583: E/AndroidRuntime(641):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 15:21:55.583: E/AndroidRuntime(641):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-07 15:21:55.583: E/AndroidRuntime(641):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-07 15:21:55.583: E/AndroidRuntime(641):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-07 15:21:55.583: E/AndroidRuntime(641):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-07 15:21:55.583: E/AndroidRuntime(641): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.badlogic.androidgames.mrnom.MrNom
11-07 15:21:55.583: E/AndroidRuntime(641):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
11-07 15:21:55.583: E/AndroidRuntime(641):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
11-07 15:21:55.583: E/AndroidRuntime(641):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
11-07 15:21:55.583: E/AndroidRuntime(641):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
11-07 15:21:55.583: E/AndroidRuntime(641):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
11-07 15:21:55.583: E/AndroidRuntime(641):    ... 11 more
11-07 15:24:06.602: E/Trace(662): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-07 15:24:06.902: W/dalvikvm(662): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/badlogic/androidgames/mrnom/MrNom; (445)
11-07 15:24:06.902: W/dalvikvm(662): Link of class 'Lcom/badlogic/androidgames/mrnom/MrNom;' failed
11-07 15:24:06.902: D/AndroidRuntime(662): Shutting down VM
11-07 15:24:06.932: W/dalvikvm(662): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
11-07 15:24:06.952: E/AndroidRuntime(662): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-07 15:24:06.952: E/AndroidRuntime(662): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.badlogic.androidgames.mrnom/com.badlogic.androidgames.mrnom.MrNom}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.badlogic.androidgames.mrnom.MrNom
11-07 15:24:06.952: E/AndroidRuntime(662):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
11-07 15:24:06.952: E/AndroidRuntime(662):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
11-07 15:24:06.952: E/AndroidRuntime(662):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-07 15:24:06.952: E/AndroidRuntime(662):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
11-07 15:24:06.952: E/AndroidRuntime(662):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-07 15:24:06.952: E/AndroidRuntime(662):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-07 15:24:06.952: E/AndroidRuntime(662):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-07 15:24:06.952: E/AndroidRuntime(662):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 15:24:06.952: E/AndroidRuntime(662):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-07 15:24:06.952: E/AndroidRuntime(662):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-07 15:24:06.952: E/AndroidRuntime(662):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-07 15:24:06.952: E/AndroidRuntime(662):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-07 15:24:06.952: E/AndroidRuntime(662): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.badlogic.androidgames.mrnom.MrNom
11-07 15:24:06.952: E/AndroidRuntime(662):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
11-07 15:24:06.952: E/AndroidRuntime(662):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
11-07 15:24:06.952: E/AndroidRuntime(662):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
11-07 15:24:06.952: E/AndroidRuntime(662):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
11-07 15:24:06.952: E/AndroidRuntime(662):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
11-07 15:24:06.952: E/AndroidRuntime(662):    ... 11 more
```

Eclipse doesn't show me any error on code. Everything looks ok but doesn't work :(

Can you help me with this. No idea where is the problem. Thank you

Comment: You got `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.badlogic.androidgames.mrnom.MrNom
`. Looks like the class is missing in classpath.

Comment: how can restore or add the classpath? thanks

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432744/adding-jars-to-classpath-eclipse-android)

Comment: I removed the /src and /gen from the project Java Build path and added again but the result is the same :( any idea? Thank you so much