# "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException" (Using spigot / Bukkit) (Eclipse)

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm trying to implement sending a simple email using JavaMail in spigot 1.8.3 using eclipse.

I have tried searching online for two days now, I've tried every single Google result that has appeared.

I made a class to send the email but when the send method is called i get the following stack trace:

```
[16:07:44] [Server thread/ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling
ServerManager v1.0 (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException
at net.mcviral.dev.plugins.servermanager.util.Email.send(Email.java:61) ~[?:?]
at net.mcviral.dev.plugins.servermanager.main.ServerManager.onEnable(ServerManager.java:43) ~[?:?]
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:321) ~[spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:335) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:405) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R1.CraftServer.loadPlugin(CraftServer.java:356) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:316) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.q(MinecraftServer.java:402) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.k(MinecraftServer.java:370) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:325) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:211) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:505) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.MessagingException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:101) ~[spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:86) ~[spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
... 13 more
```

I have referenced mail.jar and activation.jar from JavaMail as external jars.

The class i'm using to send the email is called "Email.java"

My plugin's main class is "ServerManager.java"

My main class' onEnable() [method](http://pastebin.com/iP20kRuL)

My Email [class](http://pastebin.com/1TaXUivA)

I've tried multiple ways of doing this, I've tried making a "lib" folder and putting mail.jar and activation.jar in there and then adding them to the build path, I've tried editing my manifest.mf file to include them, but nothing on any site i can find seems to work, they all have replies saying it fixed it for them but they just don't work for me, multiple ones have said about editing your classpath, I've tried doing that too but I'm not sure i understood how to do that much.

Just to clarify, I have no errors in eclipse, it's only when I run the spigot server that i get the class not found error.

Thanks for any help in advance.

EDIT:

My manifest file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: E:\Main Doccuments\Programming\Java/mail.jar;E:\Main Doccuments\Programming\Java/activation.jar
```

**Not solved but best answer**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432744/adding-jars-to-classpath-eclipse-android could probably help

Comment: Can you explain in detail how you verified the manifest part. Can you unpack your jar and check the manifest in that has the class path of the missing class ?

Comment: I already stated that it's added to my build path.

Comment: This is not the manifest file. Please update the question and not as a comment here.

Comment: How do you build your project ? Is it Maven ?

Comment: Right clicking project > Export > Jar > Name + finish, I'm completely new to the whole classpath / manifest thing, i have no clue what i'm doing with it EDIT: It says in the question that it's eclipse

Comment: Have you tried keeping your jar to server lib ?

Comment: What? I don't understand.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1) Have you used following 2 jars ?

- mail.jar
- activation.jar

2) Try switching to latest jars if issue still persist.

3) Make sure jar are available in class-path and there are no version conflicts.

4) Try upgrading you java version to 1.6+ if using lower versions.

5)
Add the jars to your WEB-INF/lib folder
Add the jars to Java Build Path > Libraries

6) Last but not the least if above solution dosnt work try to put the jar file in you server lib folder and validate.

Comment: I'm using java 1.8 and as i said both jars are in my prject and project build path.

Comment: I suspect issue with manifest file "/" which is different from rest of the url "E:\Main Doccuments\Programming\Java/mail.jar;E:\Main Doccuments\Programming\Java/activation.jar"

Also shoudnt class path be something like Class-Path: abc.jar def.jar

Comment: Changed it to backslash, didn't work.

Comment: I have feeling that you have not added jar to your project lib or not included it to class path properly. Can you please put screen shot of your eclipse java build-path > library ?

Comment: Build path: http://prntscr.com/6keodj

Comment: As i've said before, what server/lib folder, also, what do you mean WEB-INF folder, as i said, i'm completely new to classpath things, thank you for continuing to help me.

Comment: Try step 5) from my answer by copying jar internally to project lib and adding thme to class path

Comment: As i've said (getting tired of saying it) i don't know what the WEB-INF folder is and the jars ARE in the libraries like i showed you with the screenshot.

Comment: Do you have any lib folder in your project ? can you also share your folder structure ?

Comment: No: http://prntscr.com/6kew8y